# Home come Object.assign works for sending in a copy of the object to a function while the spread operator doesn't?

Tags: typescript

Why doesn't the spread operator work in this case ? Object.assign works.

```
class User
{
    private _id: number;

    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;

    constructor(_id: number)
    {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    setAllDetails(_firstName:string, _lastName: string)
    {
        this.firstName = _firstName;
        this.lastName = _lastName;
    }

    get id(): number
    {
        return this._id;
    }

    set id(id:number)
    {
        this._id = id;
    }

}

let user:User = new User(0);
const newUser = { ...user }; // This doesn't work
// const newUser = (<any>Object).assign({}, user); // This works
addUser(newUser);

function addUser(user:User)
{
    return "";
}
```

```
tsc -t es6 object-copy.ts
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR is that TypeScript does not type `Object.assign` correctly.

The spread operator only copies the "own" properties of an object.
The user in `let user: User = new User(0);` does not actually have the property `setAllDetails`. You can verify this by calling `user.hasOwnProperty('setAllDetails')`. The `setAllDetails` method actually belongs to the class object itself, `User`. `User` is the prototype of `user`. You can verify this with `Object.getPrototypeOf(user)`. When you try to access a property on an object what JavaScript does when the property is not found is look at that object's prototype and continue up the prototype chain until it finds a definition for that property, or returns `undefined` if it cannot.

`Object.assign` actually only copies "own" properties too, but TypeScript types the return type as being the intersection of the types of its arguments. So in this case `Object.assign({}, user)` is being typed as `{} & User` which is `User`. It's rather unfortunate.

Comment: I think you meant `(user.hasOwnProperty('setAllDetails')`